# How do I change my Apple ID’s rescue email if I forgot my security question's answers?

Tags: email, security, password

I had my rescue email to my old email that I deleted later. Then I realized that I forgot my security passwords and the only way to find it was to send an email to your rescue email. I didn't know what to do since its been a long time since I deleted that email. What should I do?

Comment: What does this have to do with Apple?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about Apple.

Answer (score 3):

When you do not know your security questions and have no recovery email access, the best thing to do is to call applecare. You can find the phone numbers [in this link](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232).

When you have two-step vertification enabled, apple can't reset your password. Without your recovery code, your apple id will be useless.